# Extracting load info on Abaqus with Python

Tags: mechanical-engineering, finite-element-method, aerospace-engineering, abaqus

I have a model on Abaqus that I've managed to run some 85 jobs on manually. Between jobs, only the loads vary, and I select these loads by **resuming** what I need and **suppressing** what I don't with my mouse (essentially, choosing k out of n pre-defined loads every time).

I'm new to scripting on Abaqus with Python, but I have been digging a fair amount through the official scripting guide, with no help. The task I'm working on requires me to extract, **FOR EACH JOB**, all *active* loads with their component magnitudes, and elements that they act on.

**Query 1:**

- Logically, one should be able to find job-specific loads from the corresponding odb file. But I'm unable to find forces by probing into it
  *(odb.rootAssembly->steps->...?)*.
- Going into the mdb *(mdb.model->steps->loadStates)*, however, simply lists
  down all the n pre-defined loads, which isn't very unhelpful. I need the k choices I make for each simulation.

Where do I find this information?

**Query 2:**

In general, how do I get for any element or node set, the elements or nodes in that set? (I believe nodes and elements are numbered in Abaqus)

---

I'll appreciate any help whatsoever. Thanks.